# Using Password Hash from SQL to Authenticate Windows C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, hash, directoryservices, rngcryptoserviceprovider

My plan is the following:

- Add logon name to SQL database.
- Save service account username and
  password to SQL database against each of these users, as a hash.
- User opens up app on their PC, it reads their logon name, checks if the
  service account credentials are there, if they are, pull them down
  and use them to authenticate against the domain network.
- If the users' logon name isn't there, throw an error.

Is this possible? If so, does anyone know how to translate the hash for Windows Authentication?

Comment: Don't know if my post was unclear, but I'm getting the user to authenticate against the network with a different account, so no. The service account may have different domain permissions etc which we don't want deployed to other users.

Comment: Steve I think your question would be better suitable for http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I don't think so, as the main thing I need to find out is how to convert a password hash so I can use for windows authentication....?

Comment: do you know the hashing algorithm? i doubt it... https://www.google.co.uk/?q=how%20to%20encrypt%20hash%20passwords

Comment: As a possible strategy, you could try writing a stored procedure using C#  that ties to the windows API for authentication.

Comment: HashPsi, are you able to expand on that slightly?

Comment: You can't specify a password on logon when using windows authentication. Just use windows authentication as login-method in SQL-Server and make sure, server and client are in the same Domain or in trusted domains.